# Clock simul time control

Tags: time-control, simultaneous

We would like to organise a simultaneous exhibiton at our chess club, but as we only have the room booked for 2.5hrs, we fear that it might not be over in the given time. I've heard about clock simuls, but I haven't found any "rules" on how to set the time control for each player. I'm assuming that the exhibitor should have a lot more time than the challengers (as he needs to spend time at different boards while all his clocks might be running simultaneously) but I don't know how much time would be fair to set (given that the simul should last for 2hrs, for example). Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: How many players do you expect to be there and what is the rating difference between the participants and the master player? In large simuls, use of clocks is not really practical I believe. Also you could think of introducing clocks only towards the end when few players are left.

Comment: @user1583209 that is a great idea, thank you! It's going to be a small simul, we expect around 20 people and the rating difference should be at least 400 rating points.

Answer (score 2):

> A chess simultaneous display is where a strong player takes on more than one opponent simultaneously. Sometimes this is done with clocks but more usually without, **when people must move when the simul giver arrives at their board**.

Source: [Chess Simul – Advice on giving and taking part](https://waters.me/chess/chess-simul-advice-on-giving-and-taking-part/), emphasis is mine

I would suggest using a single (normal) clock for all games. If a player (not the simul giver) has not ended their game after that time limit expires, then they lose on time. In this system, the simul giver cannot lose on time.

I would also advise that there is an arbiter present to prevent unreasonable delays when the simul giver comes to a player's board. In some simuls, a player is allowed three passes when the simul giver arrives at their board.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Yes, we will have an arbiter at the event. I see what you're suggesting, but I think that might be a bit unfair for the challengers. For instance, some games may end up in closed positions - which might require a greater number of moves to finish, and while the challenger could make a move quickly, he would also have to wait for the exhibitor to go around all tables until they get to make a move in turn. That is why I was thinking of giving the exhibitor some time as well, so that he could manage the matches such that all of them can finish fairly in the given time.

Comment: @Abigail: Done!